# Adding a new object to an existing array of data document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new at MongoDB and I want to append an "address 2" to the "location" array of my "CUSTOMER" document that has first name of "Jimmy".

The collection is like this:

```
db.collection.insert(
  {
    "CUSTOMER": {
      "first name": "Jimmy",
      "location": [{"address": {"num": 1}}]
    }
  }
);
```

I tried the following, but it created a new set insted putting a new address inside the array of location:

```
db.collection.update({"CUSTOMER.first name": "Jimmy"}, {$set:{"location":{"address": "num":2 }}});
```

I tried to put the "location" prior to the $set put it doesn't work.

I need the right prototype of doing such thing.

The expected outcome is the following:

```
db.collection.insert(
  {
    "CUSTOMER": {
      "first name": "Jimmy",
      "location": [{{"address": "num": 1}},
                   {"address": "num": 2}}
]
    }
  }
);
```

To sum up, I want to put a new address to the array of location above.

Comment: can you post expected output?

Comment: { "CUSTOMER": { "first name": "Jimmy", "location": [{{"address": {"num": 1}}, {"address": {"num": 2}] } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$set won't help here you'll have to use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator

```
db.customers.update({"CUSTOMER.first name" : "Jimmy"}, {$push: {"CUSTOMER.location": {"address" : {"num" : 1}}}})
```